# How do I validate the PARes signature?

Tags: java, signature

In Verified by Visa and MasterCard SecureCode a PARes message is generated.  It contains a signature.  How do I use the signature to verify that the message has not been tampered with?

In section 6.1 the [instructions](https://usa.visa.com/dam/VCOM/download/merchants/verified-by-visa-acquirer-merchant-implementation-guide.pdf) for Visa say:

'Use the Visa 3-D Secure Root Certificate to validate the cryptographic signature in the PARes message to ensure its authenticity and integrity. '

But I am unsure of how to do this.  An example in Java would be a big help.

Comment: Hello, Did you decide this problem ? Can you show how to do Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per section 9 you need to obtain

- 3-D Secure: Protocol Specification—Core Functions
- 3-D Secure:
  Functional Requirements—Merchant Server  Plug-in

documents from Visa. They should contain the necessary instructions.